# HANA XS destination to Cloud Connector on a different SAP Cloud Platform Sub-Account

Tags: hana, hana-xs

For combining Cloud stored data in HANA on my SAP Cloud Platform Sub-account, I use HANA XS with a connection to an On-Premise SAP ECC/ERP system. The ECC/ERP system is connected to the On-Premise Cloud Connector. This Cloud Connector is connected to my Sub-account. HANA XS uses the Cloud Connector connection in the Sub-account successfully, using the following values:

```
host = "[:virtual-host:]";
port = [:virtual-port:];
pathPrefix = "/sap/opu/odata";
proxyType = http;
proxyHost = "localhost";
proxyPort = 20003;
authType = basic;
useSSL = false;
timeout = 3000;
```

However, this only works when the HANA system is hosted on the same Sub-account as the Cloud Connector is connected to. In my current situation, the HANA system is hosted on a different Sub-account. My Sub-account has a binding to this HANA system. This HANA system can be used by all applications hosted on my Sub-account. The Cloud Connector is also connected to my Sub-account and is working fine in my front-end application.

The problem now is, I can't use the Cloud Connector connection in HANA XS. My assumption is: proxy to localhost:200003 refers to the SAP Cloud Platform Sub-account on which the HANA system is hosted. This means the Cloud Connector on the other Sub-account cannot be used.

How do I get my destination to refer to the Cloud Connector on my own SAP Cloud Platform Sub-account?

Answer (score 0):

SCC it will create gateway which enables the connection between SCC to Target system and also it enables some ports to access the on-premise system which you configured in SCC. By default port: 20003 for on-premise.

It will accept your request based on your virtual host and won't care about how many requests it is getting(process the request one after another). Though it does require a virtual host along with virtual host number based on these to properties it will identify the subaccount and access control in SCC.

**OR**

You can instead specify the SCC sub account location Id in SCP destination and it will only access the sub-account access controls.

From there u can in use application by importing destination.